# Sum data with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not even sure my title is correct, but hope it will all make sense either way. 
I am trying to reduce a dataframe with this format by means of column D. The end result should be a DF with a D-interval of 0.2, and all the other columns should be summed up for that interval, i.e. first column of A should be 1.738 + 1.738 + 2.719 etc.

```
         D      A        B        C       V     S  AQ
0    0.025  1.738   45.418     4.40   0.000     0   0
1    0.050  1.738   45.418     4.40   0.000     0   0
2    0.075  2.719  179.327     1.12   0.000     0   0
3    0.100  2.719  179.327     1.12   0.000     0   0
```

Any good tips on how to achieve this? 
I suppose I could do it with loops and lists, but I would suspect there to be a better way. Apply a lambda-function somehow? 
Sincerely,
Fredrik

Comment: Something like `df.drop('D', axis=1).groupby(df['D']//0.2).sum()` would do.

Comment: Thank you! That worked quite well (without going through the data sets too deeply)! I suppose I would have to add a new column D again afterwards? Thank you a lot. I don't really know how to mark it as answered, but you surely did.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever might be interested I found another method that worked better. For some reason this proposed method from Quang Hoang did not sum the way intended. 
But from this link: 
I could make out this:

```
df = df.drop('D', axis=1).groupby(pd.cut(df["D"], arange(0, len(df)+0.2, 0.2))).sum().reset_index()
```

which would produce:

```
                  D      A      H       B       C
0        (0.0, 0.2]  5.803  103.0  86.405  912.78
1        (0.2, 0.4]  8.195    8.0  56.608  287.22
2        (0.4, 0.6]  8.078   10.0  56.093  259.27
3        (0.6, 0.8]  8.150    3.0  48.559  281.24
4        (0.8, 1.0]  8.134    2.0  36.809  357.66
```